# How to mock MatChipInput when testing with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-material

I have set-up a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-viyyad) with a basic showing of what the issue is.

Basically when I try to trigger an event on a MatFormField which contains a MatChipList I am getting an error of

```
 Cannot read property 'stateChanges' of undefined at MatChipInput._onInput
```

I have tried overriding the MatChip module with a replacement mock for MatInput. I've also tried overriding the directive.

HTML

```
 <h1>Welcome to app!!</h1>

 <div>
  <mat-form-field>
   <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let contrib of contributors; let idx=index;" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeContributor(idx)">
     {{contrib.fullName}}
    </mat-chip>
    <input  id="contributor-input"
        placeholder="contributor-input"
        #contributorInput
        [formControl]="contributorCtrl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur">
  </mat-chip-list>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { COMMA, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

contributors = [{fullName: 'foo bar'}];
removable = true;
addOnBlur = false;
separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [
    ENTER,
    COMMA,
];

contributorCtrl = new FormControl();

filteredPeople: Observable<Array<any>>;

@Input() peopleArr = [];

constructor() {
   this.filteredPeople = this.contributorCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), map((value: any) => 
this.searchPeople(value)));
 }

 searchPeople(searchString: string) {
    const filterValue = String(searchString).toLowerCase();
    const result = this.peopleArr.filter((option) => option.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    return result;
  }
}
```

SPEC

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { 
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule, 
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting 
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {  MatFormFieldModule, 
      MatAutocompleteModule, 
      MatInputModule,
      MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  const mockPeopleArray = [
    { personId: 1,
      email: 'foo1@bar.com',
      department: 'fake1',
      username: 'foo1',
      fullName: 'Foo Johnson'
     },
     { personId: 2,
      email: 'foo2@bar.com',
      department: 'fake1',
      username: 'foo2',
      fullName: 'John Fooson'
     },
     { personId: 3,
      email: 'foo1@bar.com',
      department: 'fake2',
      username: 'foo3',
      fullName: 'Mary Smith'
     }
 ];


 let app: AppComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
 let nativeElement: HTMLElement;

 beforeAll( ()=> {
  TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, 
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  });
  beforeEach(
   async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
       RouterTestingModule,
       MatFormFieldModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       MatAutocompleteModule,
       MatChipsModule,
       MatInputModule,
       NoopAnimationsModule
       ],
       declarations: [AppComponent]
     }).compileComponents();

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
   app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
   nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
  })
 );
 it(
 'should render title \'Welcome to app!!\' in a h1 tag', async(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(nativeElement.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to app!!');
})
);

it('searchPeople should trigger and filter', (done) => {
  app.peopleArr = mockPeopleArray;

  const expected = [
    { personId: 3,
      email: 'foo1@bar.com',
      department: 'fake2',
      username: 'foo3',
      fullName: 'Mary Smith'
     }
  ];

  const myInput = <HTMLInputElement> 
  nativeElement.querySelector('#contributor-input');
  expect(myInput).not.toBeNull();
  myInput.value = 'Mar';
  spyOn(app, 'searchPeople').and.callThrough();
  myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const myDiv = nativeElement.querySelector('#contrib-div');
        expect(app.searchPeople).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mar');
        app.filteredPeople.subscribe(result => 
        expect(result).toEqual(<any>expected));
        done();
    });
  });
 });
```

Comment: Hi there. Please try to refrain from adding (or re-adding) chatty material to posts. Volunteer editors try to edit/curate material here to fall into technical writing standards, so that posts are clear and succinct for future readers.

Comment: To give an idea of what constitutes chatty material, I sometimes offer this advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting:

> Cannot read property 'stateChanges' of undefined at
>   MatChipInput._onInput

since Angular hasn't finished bindings yet at the time of firing`myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))`

To remedy this you should call [fixture.detectChanges](http://You%20must%20tell%20the%20TestBed%20to%20perform%20data%20binding%20by%20calling%20fixture.detectChanges()) first so that Angular will perform data binding.

Then you do not need to make this test asynchrounous since all actions are executed synchronously.

Now regarding your `searchPeople` method. It will be called twice since you start subscription with initial value by using `startWith('')`:

```
this.contributorCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')
```

So you need to skip the first call and check the result of the call after firing `input`  event.

```
app.filteredPeople.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(result => {
  ...
});

spyOn(app, "searchPeople").and.callThrough();

myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
expect(app.searchPeople).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Mar");
```

The whole code of the test:

```
it("searchPeople should trigger and filter", () => {
  app.peopleArr = mockPeopleArray;

  const expected = [
    {
      personId: 3,
      email: "foo1@bar.com",
      department: "fake2",
      username: "foo3",
      fullName: "Mary Smith"
    }
  ];

  fixture.detectChanges();
  const myInput = nativeElement.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(
    "#contributor-input"
  );
  expect(myInput).not.toBeNull();
  myInput.value = "Mar";

  app.filteredPeople.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(result => 
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  );

  spyOn(app, "searchPeople").and.callThrough();

  myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
  expect(app.searchPeople).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Mar");
});
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-lpfvsr?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)**

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! And thank you for the detailed explanation. One minor note, in Jasmine toBe would detect the two objects as always different. toEqual appears to do a different type of comparison.   expect(result).toEqual(expected) functions as anticipated.

Comment: @E.Maggini Thank you for that note:)